# Could somebody please explain the Matlab std() implementation logic?

Tags: matlab

According to the documentation, the [std](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html) function computes the standard deviation of each column. However, when I used the standard deviation formula for the first column, my result differed from that of Matlab.

The Matlab results are the following:

```
A = [4 -5 1; 2 3 5; -9 1 7];
S = std(A)
S = 1×3
7.0000    4.1633    3.0551
```

By using the [Standard Deviation Formula](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/19/b3/3e19b3315ed39dac039cd471dc4bb756.gif) for the first column, I got:

```
sqrt(((4 + 1) ^ 2 + (2 + 1) ^ 2 + ( - 9 + 1) ^ 2) / 3) =
5.71547606649
```

5.71547606649 is different from 7.00. What am I doing wrong D: ?

Thanks a lot for your time and have a wonderful day :D !

Comment: [corrected std or uncorrected std? ;)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation)

Comment: @AnderBiguri What do you mean? I think is just regular std right?

Comment: [Is it?](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html#bune77u)

Comment: Ander's comments are links. Read them.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I do not know how I overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the std formula. According to matlab documentation, which says `sqrt(1/(N-1) etc)` so you must divide by 2 not by 3  .

See the chapter [More About](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html#bune5v_-10) of std documentation.

Also, you can use this to use the std formula with `1/N, std(A,1)`. The second input specifies the formula you want to use, with 0 you use `1/(N-1)` formula (default) with 1 you use `1/N` formula.